# How to fill a corny with shop bought mini-keg beer?

Tags: corny-keg

I have not had time to get brew ready for Christmas, so I’m looking to at least fill my Corny kegs with some shop bought beer I.e. 5 litre keg or a box of cider, just so people have the novelty of serving it from the tap when they come over.

What should the procedure be? What are the risks? Will the beer just taste stale after a few days? Etc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to avoid as much oxygen as possible. So, something like a "[closed transfer system](http://www.homebrewing.com/articles/closed-transfer-system/)" from the original container to your keg: flood your keg with CO2, transfer the beer via a tube, don't pour. You will lose some carbonation, but that you can add by force carbonating the keg.

I don't know for how long the beer will be ok.